# Why deleteOne & findById of mongoose work on deleted id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

Currently developing an API with nodejs that communicates with a MongoDB database, I noticed a special behavior after deleting a document.

Indeed, my API has several endpoints that allow to retrieve all the animals in the database, to retrieve a specific one using the corresponding id or to delete a specific one, again using the id of the document to delete.

The results I don't understand happen once a document is deleted. Indeed, as you can see in the picture below, when I delete the document of the animal called "Johnny" the queries to find it via its id or to delete it via the same ID continue to work, even if the get returns nothing and the deletion indicates that no operation has been performed.

[image]

Personally I expected the same behavior as if I passed a wrong id for a deletion (visible below), but if the id has already been assigned in the database the queries work even after a deletion.

[image: When I tried to deleted a wrong ID]

Does MongoDB have a "cache" of deleted documents in order to perform a rollback in case of unwanted deletion?

You will find below the different endpoints that use find, deleteOne & findById

```js
exports.getAllAnimal = (req, res, next) => {
    Animal.find().sort({'customer' : 1})
    .then(animals => res.status(200).send(animals))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send({ error: error.message }));
};


exports.getOneAnimal = (req, res, next) => {
    Animal.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
        .then(animal => res.status(200).send(animal))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send({ error: error.message }));
};


exports.deleteAnimal = (req, res, next) => {
    Animal.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id })
        .then(thing => res.status(200).send({ message : 'Animal successfully deleted'}))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send({ error: error.message }));

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB does not cache deleted id anywhere.

The thing is that when you said `I passed a wrong id for a deletion ...` you are passing an id with the same length but not in the required format. That's why Mongoose is throwing you an error.

However, if you follow the id structure of MongoDB to create an id that does not exist in the database and run an operation against it, MongoDB will still return you with success and an empty result.

Try using `5ea08034385a46666b05020f` and run the `.findById()` query function against it. It's going to return you with a success an empty result.

The success only means that the operation is successful, but it doesn't necessarily mean that it actually finds something in the database.

I don't have access to your database, so the id is generated randomly but following the MongoDB `ObjectId` rules below:

The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:

1. a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId’s creation, measured in
2. seconds since the Unix epoch
3. a 5-byte random value
4. a 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value

Generate arbitrary MongoDB ObjectId:
https://observablehq.com/@hugodf/mongodb-objectid-generator

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ! 

Did I must switch the String ID with ObjectID object in my API ?

Comment: So what's your project trying to do exactly? I am just a bit confused.

Comment: It's just a try to be honest. I would like to manage a database of animals that's all. 

I was wondering if in "getOneAnimal" and "deleteAnimal" I must make ObjectId(req.params.id) instead of just req.params.id

Comment: Perhaps you can add other unique identifiers like a custom nickname or id for each individual animal when you are trying to do some other operations. Because `ObjectId` is strictly reserved for MongoDB only. So what are you passing in `req.params.id`?

Comment: Juste the id of the mongoDB document

Comment: Vous parlez francais? Ok, the your  ` _id: req.params.id ` works fine.

Comment: Je suis français oui :)

Ok, thanks for the info :)

Comment: No problem. Est-ce que j'ai résolu votre question?